# Print on a single line not working Python 3

Tags: python, printing, text-files, readfile

I'm very new to programming and am working on some code to extract data from a bunch of text files. I've been able to do this however the data is not useful to me in Excel. Therefore, I would like to print it all on a single line and separate it by a special character, which I can then delimit in Excel.

Here is my code:

```
import os
data=['Find me','find you', 'find us']
with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\File.txt', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:

        for a in data:
            string=a

            if string in line:

                print (line,end='*') #print on same line

    inF.close()
```

So basically what I'm doing is finding if a keyword is on that line and then printing that line if it is.

Even though I have print(,end='*'), I don't get the print on a single line. It outputs:

```
Find me

*find you

*find us
```

Where is the problem? (I'm using Python 3.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're not removing the newline characters from your lines before printing them. The usual way to do this is with `strip()`, eg:

```
print(line.strip(), end='*')
```

You'll also print multiple copies of the line if more than one of your special phrases appear in the line. To avoid that, add a `break` statement after your print, or (better, but a more advanced construct that might not make sense until you're used to generator expressions) use `if any(keyword in line for keyword in data):`

You also don't need to explicitly close the input file - the point of the `with open(...) as ...:` context manager is that it closes the file when exiting it.

And I would avoid using `string` as a variable name - it doesn't tell anyone anything about what the variable is used for, and it can cause confusion if you end up using the built-in `string` module for anything. It's not as bad as shadowing a built-in constructor like `list`, but it's worth avoiding. Especially since it does nothing for you here, you can just use `if a in line:` here if you don't want to use the `any()` version above.

In addition to all that, if your data is not extremely large (and I hope it's not if you're trying to fit it all on one line) you'll get tidier code and avoid the trailing delimiter by using the `.join()` method on strings, eg something like:

```
import os
data=['Find me','find you', 'find us']
with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\File.txt', 'r') as inF:
    print "*".join(line.strip() for line in inF if any(keyword in line for keyword in data))
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's so simple!
Thank you very much for the extra advice too! I appreciate the time taken to add that in.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of work with spreadsheets and Python, make sure you look over the built-in `csv` module - it does a lot for you when you're dealing with delimited files.

Comment: Yeah I've been looking into it more, however this somewhat dodgy way was done to get a quick result. But thanks again!